# Команды в UserControl. Зачем нужны параметры в разметке

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, mvvm

А теперь вопрос по командам...
Что-то мне кажется я зачастил.

Итак, если SearchBox - это UserControl, который содержит в себе TextBox(на самом деле InputBox - тоже UserControl, который расширяет стандартный TextBox возможностью устанавливать placeholder) и Button. Мне нужно реализовать команду, которая будет срабатывать каждый раз, когда у SearchBox изменяется текст.

Я сделал так:
1. В codebehind объявил команду:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"Command",
typeof( ICommand ),
typeof( SearchBox ) );

public ICommand Command 
{
   get { return (ICommand)GetValue( CommandProperty ); }
   set { SetValue( CommandProperty, value ); }
}
```

Подписался на событие TextChanged у TextBox'а:

```
private void InputBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Command?.Execute( Text );
}
```

Вопрос. Зачем в разметке нужно указывать параметры у команды? Где и как это может пригодиться? В моем случае, пользователь моего SearchBox'а вообще не должен подвязывать какие-то параметры к команде:

```
<local:SearchBox Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"/>
```

Но при этом он должен знать, что при выполнении этой команды, если мы сделаем стандартную обертку `RelayCommand`, в параметре обработчика будет текст, который в данный момент в SearchBox присутствует

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начнём немного издалека, команды используют в основном, чтобы отделить codebehind и саму логику приложения. Посему очень часто и используют сам паттерн MVVM. Сначала отвечу на ваши вопросы:

- > Зачем в разметке нужно указывать параметры у команды? Где и как это может пригодиться?

Для того, чтобы передать что-то из разметки в саму бизнес логику. К примеру, вам нужно передать пароль в метод авторизации, сам PasswordBox не даёт вам возможности привязать его поле Password к бизнес логике, посему, нужно его передать. Дав имя элементу, например `PasswordTB`, вы можете через `CommandParameter` указать что вам нужно передать, например если нужно указать только поле пароля, то это делается так:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Authentificate}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName = PasswordTB, Path = Password}"/>
```

Пожалуй, тут все с ответом. Но, будет встречный вопрос, для чего вам своя реализация с "автоподтягиванием" текста из этого элемента? Если вам вдруг понадобится вытаскивать из других элементов что-то, то вы снова создадите новую реализацию?

Comment: Я не знаю, а как тогда мне выполнять команду, когда текст в SearchBox изменяется?

Comment: @Bretbas А вам действительно нужно динамическое исполнение по вводу текста? Тогда вопрос, зачем вам кнопка, если у вас он исполняется сразу?

Comment: Я хочу повторить контрол поиска, как у VS 2017 в правом верхнем меню. У VS по нажатию на кнопку поиска, просто TextBox получает фокус

Comment: @Bretbas 1) Для этого вовсе не обязательно использовать свой контрол и заточенный под 1 контрол реализацию ICommand интерфейса

Comment: @Bretbas 
2) Уже есть такие контролы, которые реализованы в библиотеках типа [MahApps](http://mahapps.com)
3) Если уж очень хочется сделать именно так, то проще сделать это на через ViewModel, если вы используете MVVM. Или как вы сделали в CodeBehind

Comment: Я это все делаю в целях обучения. Я не хочу использовать какие-либо готовые решения. Я хочу реализовать свой контрол, который буду в дальнейшем использовать. Мне нужно сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку поиска, TextBox получал фокус. Это я сделал. Теперь, я хочу реализовать такую фишку, чтобы я мог подвязать свою команду к этому контролу, и моя команда начала выполняться каждый раз, когда текст в окне SearchBox'а изменяется. Все. Я это все сделал. Но меня смутил тот факт, что в разметке можно указывать у команд параметры, а у меня, как вы увидели, она передается в codebehind

Comment: @Bretbas Тогда, я так полагаю, вопрос исчерпан?

Comment: Не совсем. Вы мне скажите, в моем случае, нужно так поступать, или как-то иначе? Я так понимаю у SearchBox'а не должно быть параметров команды внутри верстки?

Comment: @Bretbas Раз ваша команда, уже знает о вашем SearchBox'е и вы не планируете дальше экспериментировать с командами, то оставляйте как есть. Но, если вы думаете дальше экспериментировать, то, рекомендую все-так использовать уже готовые реализации IComman (Например RelayCommand), так как в вашем контроле есть Button, то вы можете без проблем передавать нужные вам параметры.

Comment: Причем здесь RelayCommand? У меня есть реализация. Я имею ввиду, какую Вы команду предложите для SearchBox? Чтобы я или кто-нибудь другой смог подставить свою в разметке? Я вот придумал, что каждый раз, когда текст будет изменяться в SearchBox, должна выпоняться команда. Так же в реализации Button, при щелчке мышкой на кнопке, выполняется внутренняя команда в Button'е, правильно?

Comment: @Bretbas Давайте проясним следующий момент, под словом "предложить команду"  вы имеете ввиду, посоветовать
 сам код основанный на вашей реализации или же посоветовать вам реализацию интерфейса ICommand?

Comment: Да у меня есть реализация ICommand:) С параметром и без. Я имел ввиду, посоветовать, что должен делать SearchBox, чтобы использовал команды с параметром к примеру. Чтобы задавать его в разметке

Comment: @Bretbas Понял, ну, это уже на ваше усмотрение :) Если хотите, например, можете получить целый DataContext странице, где сейчас ваш SearchBox, делается это просто 
`<Window .... x:Name="MainWindow" > 
<local:SearchBox CommandProperty="{Binding ElementName = MainWindow, Path = DataContext}" ... />
`, например, если у вас есть ListBox, где, вероятнее всего, вы выводите результаты, то можете найти его через DataContext по имени, и поменять результаты, назначив новый DataSource, и так далее, если я правильно понял, то это всё :) Тут уже вы сами решайте :)

Comment: Стоп, а как мне сделать так, чтобы в обработчике TextChanged моего контрола, не выполнять явно команду, а передавать к примеру значение свойства Text прямо из верстки, примерно вот так: `<local:SearchBox Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>`

Comment: @Bretbas Для этого надо "кликать" по кнопке, которая находится в вашем контроле

Comment: Но в кнопке уже реализовано свойство `CommandParameter`. А как мне реализовать его в своем UserControl'е? Такое вообще делается? Или только готовое надо использовать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69611/discussion-between-wardef-and-bretbas).